# Connection between PCP and L=SL

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, space-bounded, pcp

The book by Arora and Barak contains in chapter notes on PCP

> We note that Dinur's general strategy is somewhat reminiscent of the zig-zag construction of expander graphs and Reingold's deterministic logspace algorithm for undirected connectivity described in Chapter 20, which suggests that more connections are waiting to be made between these different areas of research. (pg 494)

What precisely is meant by this reminiscence? Is there a common property/lemma than can be "factored out" of these two proofs?

Comment: The way things happened, Irit was inspired by Omer's proof when she came up with the PCP proof.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The precise answer to your question is given by Oded Goldreich in his article "Bravely, Moderately: A Common Theme in Four Recent Works".

Here is the link: [https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/p_brave.html](https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eoded/p_brave.html)